# I want to change the session duration of iam role credentials to 12 hours

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I made a role and by using this commend

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxrole/rolename --role-session-name s3sdawx
```

i got credentials
After obtaining temporary credentials with the command
I accessed s3 with these credentials!

by the way Token expires after 1 hour. So, as shown in the picture, I changed the maximum session duration to 12 hours, got the temporary credentials through the above command again and tried to apply it again, but it still expires after 1 hour! I wonder what method should be used to extend it to 12 hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `--duration-seconds 43200` to your command:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxrole/rolename --role-session-name s3sdawx --duration-seconds 43200
```

Comment: thank you! can i ask one more thing? If my credentials expire after 12 hours, do I need to re-issue my credentials every 12 hours? Is there any way to make it automatically update and apply in the code? I write credenatials in .env and use it

Comment: @user15322469 Depends when the code executes. If its EC2 or ECS, its all done automatically for you. If its external setup,  you can have some cron job or some equivalent of it automatically doing the renewal.